# Arrowheads in VectorStyle and StreamStyle doesn't work properly in VectorPlot and StreamPlot, respectively. A bug?

Tags: plotting

I'm using Mathematica 10.0.2 for Mac.

`Arrowheads` given in `VectorStyle` for `VectorPlot` doesn't work for some combinations of directives.

Beginning with the following plot:

```
VectorPlot[{1, 1}, {x, 0, 8}, {y, 0, 8}]
```

[image: VectorPlot]

## Working combinations

### Example 1

```
VectorPlot[{1, 1}, {x, 0, 8}, {y, 0, 8}, VectorStyle -> Arrowheads[0]]
VectorPlot[{1, 1}, {x, 0, 8}, {y, 0, 8}, VectorStyle -> {Arrowheads[0]}]
```

[image: VectorPlot]

### Example 2

```
VectorPlot[{1, 1}, {x, 0, 8}, {y, 0, 8}, VectorStyle -> {{Black, Arrowheads[0]}}]
```

[image: VectorPlot]

### Example 3

```
VectorPlot[{1, 1}, {x, 0, 8}, {y, 0, 8}, VectorStyle -> {{Thick, Arrowheads[0]}}
```

[image: VectorPlot]

## Malfunctioning combinations

The follow codes should work in removing the arrow heads but they don't.

`Directive` is forbidden:

```
VectorPlot[{1, 1}, {x, 0, 8}, {y, 0, 8}, VectorStyle -> Directive[Arrowheads[0]]]
```

No, you can't pretend there are multiple sets of fields (cf Example 1):

```
VectorPlot[{1, 1}, {x, 0, 8}, {y, 0, 8}, VectorStyle -> {{Arrowheads[0]}}]
```

No, `Arrowheads[0]` can't be the first directive (cf Example 2):

```
VectorPlot[{1, 1}, {x, 0, 8}, {y, 0, 8}, VectorStyle -> {{Arrowheads[0], Black}}]
```

No, you can't customise both colour and thickness simultaneously, irrespective of where `Arrowheads` is:

```
VectorPlot[{1, 1}, {x, 0, 8}, {y, 0, 8}, VectorStyle -> {{Red, Thick, Arrowheads[0]}}]
VectorPlot[{1, 1}, {x, 0, 8}, {y, 0, 8}, VectorStyle -> {{Arrowheads[0], Red, Thick}}]
```

---

The same is true for `StreamPlot` and `StreamStyle`. Is all this a bug?

---

On Wolfram Cloud, which I guess is equivalent to 10.1, every combination described above works fine except

```
VectorPlot[{1, 1}, {x, 0, 8}, {y, 0, 8}, VectorStyle -> Directive[Arrowheads[0]]]
StreamPlot[{1, 1}, {x, 0, 8}, {y, 0, 8}, StreamStyle -> Directive[Arrowheads[0]]]
```

`Arrowheads` is a directive supported by `Graphics` [(ref.)](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Arrowheads.html), and any directives supported by `Graphics` should be able to appear inside `Directive` [(ref.)](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Directive.html).

Answer (score 5):

It is probably a bug in `V10.02`.

In `V10.1`:

`Directive` does not work on each individual element of the `Graphics`. If you want to use it then you can do it like this:

```
VectorPlot[{1, 1}, {x, 0, 8}, {y, 0, 8}, 
 VectorStyle -> {Arrowheads[0], Directive[Red, Thick]}]
```

[image]

For the rest examples, they all work fine.

**Update:**

`Arrowhead` is a `Directive` as you said and it do appear in the `Graphics`  `Directive` of the graphics.

```
VectorPlot[{1, 1}, {x, 0, 8}, {y, 0, 8}, 
  VectorStyle -> Directive[Arrowheads[0]]] // FullForm
```

[image]

But it does not work unless `Arrowhead` is grouped in list with each `Arrow`:

```
VectorPlot[{1, 1}, {x, 0, 8}, {y, 0, 8}, 
  VectorStyle -> Arrowheads[0]] // FullForm
```

[image]

Comment: My first malfunctioning example should work. For example, this works: `VectorPlot[{1, 1}, {x, 0, 8}, {y, 0, 8}, VectorStyle -> Directive[Red]]`. Like `Red`, `Arrowheads` is a directive supported by `Graphics` [(ref.)](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Arrowheads.html), and any directives supported by `Graphics` can appear inside `Directive` [(ref.)](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Directive.html).

Comment: @Taiki check update.

Comment: Thank you for the investigation. I'll include it in my report to WRI.